# Covering index decision in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My MySQL slow query log showed a query that looks rather simple as one of the slowest queries run on my server:

```
SELECT result_known,AVG(points_total) as points
FROM tbl_points
WHERE uid IN (N,{1023 repeats}N)
GROUP BY gid
ORDER BY gid ASC;
```

I'm basically trying to find the average points total for a subgroup (set of uids, e.g. based on gender or whatever) of a group. There are individual indexes on uid and gid, but `EXPLAIN` shows that they're not being used:

```
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_points          | ALL  | combined      | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   64 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Now, the obvious solution, as I understand it, is to have a covering index over these fields:

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON dbo.tbl_points(result_known, points_total, uid, gid)
```

And indeed, this makes it use the index:

```
| id | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_points          | index | combined      | index3 | 18      | NULL |   64 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

However, I have two questions:

- In the `Extra` field, `EXPLAIN` now says "*Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort*". This is bad, right? So should I use this index or not? In dummy terms, is it more important to have `type=index` and `key=something` than what happens in the "extra" field, or not?
- What are the effects of having a covering index on large inserts? I am inserting points in this same table by doing a `JOIN`-`UPDATE` with a quite large temporary table. I wouldn't want to slow this down too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use an index to optimize the range predicate of `IN(...)`, or you can use an index to optimize out the temp table caused by the `GROUP BY` (though you make a good point that this may not work with AVG()). But you can't achieve both uses of indexes in the same SELECT.

I'm going to conclude that you can't get rid of the temp table in this particular query. The best you can do is try to keep it from going to disk by increasing `tmp_table_size`. Or if it does go to disk, configure a tmpfs filesystem and use that mount point as your `tmpdir`.

So you have to choose, do you want to search an index for your list of `uid` values? You have a really long list of uid's, so that's going to be costly just to estimate the row count. Be sure to upgrade to MySQL 5.6, which has some new optimizations in this area (see [Equality Range Optimization of Many-Valued Comparisons](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html)).

The `type=index` means it's doing an index scan, which is costly but at least it's getting results from the index alone instead of having to read table rows. So it needs fewer buffer pool pages to satisfy this query.

Answer (score 1):

`Using Temporary` in the explain output means that a temporary table was created to satisfy the group by condition. This is not very bad but much better performance can be achieved if you [optimise group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) for "Loose Index Scan".

In order for this query to avoid a temporary table, the `gid` column has to be indexed so it is the left most part of a composite key or a single column index. To further improve it, `uid` as a single column index is also a good chice:

```
CREATE INDEX uid_idx ON dbo.tbl_points(uid)
CREATE INDEX gid_idx ON dbo.tbl_points(gid)
```

**Update:**

As @Dow correctly pointed out, the use of `AVG()` disqualifies the query for index access group by calculations, only `MIN()` and `MAX()` wouldn't. The proposed indexes nevertheless should still give better performance.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, loose index scans don't work on AVG()? It says: Any other parts of the index than those from the GROUP BY referenced in the query must be constants (that is, they must be referenced in equalities with constants), except for the argument of MIN() or MAX() functions.